# Lottery probability.

Tags: probability

Let's say that a lottery operates with a pool of 200 numbers (1-200).

Each person who buys a ticket gets 50 numbers generated by the ticketing computer. The 50 numbers on any given ticket is unique within the ticket but can appear again on other tickets without limit.

Can anyone come up with an expression to determine the probability that between any X tickets, Y numbers are repeated at least once?

EDIT: Ignore the following:
What is the likely average instances in which numbers that would repeat at least once in Z tickets? (Is it even feasible to calculate this?)

Comment: If $X=3$ would $Y$ be the number of numbers that are on at least two of them?  or on all three of them?  I can't understand the question with $Z$ in it.

Comment: If X = 3, Y is the number of numbers that are on at least two of them.

Comment: From what do we draw the X tickets? X people with 1 ticket each? How we choose the tickets is very important.